# Run django tests from a browser

Tags: django, testing

I'd like to provide a browser page to help non-techies run the various tests I've created using the standard django test framework.

The ideal would be for a way to display all the tests found for an application with tick boxes against each one, so the user could choose to run all tests or just a selection.

Output would be displayed in a window/frame for review.

Anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite what you've asked, but sounds a bit like [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/), which allows non-technical users to define tests in a wiki-like syntax and run them from the browser. It is possible to link this up to Django's test framework.

Comment: Not quite what I need but very interesting.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: Marking as accepted as can't work out how else to close the question!